# Error using to_char // to_timestamp

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a database in PostgreSQL and I'm developing an application in PHP using this database.
The problem is that when I execute the following query I get a nice result in phpPgAdmin but in my PHP application I get an error.

**The query:**

```
SELECT t.t_name, t.t_firstname
   FROM teachers AS t
   WHERE t.id_teacher IN    ( 
      SELECT id_teacher FROM teacher_course AS tcourse
          JOIN course_timetable AS coursetime
          ON tcourse.course = coursetime.course
          AND to_char(to_timestamp('2010-4-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'FMD') = (coursetime.day +1)
      )
   AND t.id_teacher NOT IN (
      SELECT id_teacher FROM teachers_fill WHERE date = '2010-4-12'
   )
ORDER BY t.t_name ASC
```

**And this is the error in PHP**

```
operator does not exist: text = integer (to_timestamp('', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'FMD') =
 (courset... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). 
You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The purpose to solve this error is to use the ORIGINAL query in php with :

> $date = "2010"."-".$selected_month."-".$selected_day;

```
SELECT ...
  AND to_char(to_timestamp('$date', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'FMD') = (coursetime.day +1)
)
AND t.id_teacher NOT IN (
      SELECT id_teacher FROM teachers_fill WHERE date = '$date'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message seems quite clear to me. You are mixing strings and numbers. More precisely, you are converting a string ('2010-4-12') to a timestamp, then to a string, then comparing to an int. This is a type mess, and postgresql is quite strict with typing (for good reasons). What are you trying to do here ?

`to_char(to_timestamp('2010-4-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'FMD') = (coursetime.day +1))`

Further, you should use a TIMESTAMP, just a DATE.

If (I'm not sure) you are tring to compare the day of week from a date formated as `'YYYY-MM-DD'` to a given value (as an integer), you should better use  [date_part](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/functions-datetime.html). For example (not tested):

`date_part('dow' , to_date('2010-4-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD') ) = coursetime.day + 1`

Comment: Thank you :)
I made a mess with the types:)